# CoroutineWorker: interrupt doWork() on cancelPendingIntent action

Tags: android, android-workmanager

Is it possible to cancel the work done in `doWork()` when the cancel action from the notification is triggered?

```
class TestWorker(context: Context, parameters: WorkerParameters) :
    CoroutineWorker(context, parameters) {

    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {

        setForeground(createForegroundInfo())
        doStuff()
        return Result.success()
    }

    private fun doStuff() {
        for (i in 0..10) {
            Log.d(LOG, "Can this be interrupted?")
            Thread.sleep(1000)
        }
    }

    private fun createForegroundInfo(): ForegroundInfo {
        val cancelIntent = WorkManager.getInstance(applicationContext)
            .createCancelPendingIntent(id)

        val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(applicationContext, CHANNEL_ID)

            ...

            .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_delete, "cancel", cancelIntent)
            .build()

        createChannelIfNeeded()
        return ForegroundInfo(1, notification)
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Thread.sleep(1000)` is not interruptible by Coroutines. If you use `delay(1000)`, then it will be interruptible as per [this blog post](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/cancellation-in-coroutines-aa6b90163629#1b18).

```
private suspend fun doStuff() {
    for (i in 0..10) {
        Log.d(LOG, "Can this be interrupted?")
        delay(1000)
    }
}
```

Comment: You can ignore the delay. It can be any type of long running work there.

Comment: Then you should probably read the blog post I linked, which talks specifically about how to make your coroutine work cancellable.

Comment: Checking for isStopped helped.